# some programs not working after system restore

Tags: windows-8, system-restore

so after I did windows updates after a long time (it's for a good reason that I am not updating!) the notebook (Windows 8) failed to start correctly. After the windows loading screen, only different tones of black were flashing - probably bad graphics driver. 
Anyway, I managed to do a system restore. Although it said it wasn't successful, it works.
But now some programs won't start. From Adobe, AfterEffects starts without problems, but Photoshop and Illustrator has an error:

[image]

Microsoft Office won't open as well:

[image]
[image]
[image]

When I try to uninstall Office completely, the set-up window doesn't even come up. And what's worse... when I run a new installation from a disk, there's an error too.

[image]

I've never come across something like this.. I don't know what to do.

//Edit:
So I managed to uninstall Office through a 3rd party software.. but I still have trouble installing it back (a different error now). I run as administrator and have full user rights on the folder..
[image: installing error]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you restored your system to a restore point which was created prior to the installation of MS Office and Adobe products. As soon as you restored your system to that particular point, it deleted these programs, possibly. If that's the case, you unfortunately have to re-install these programs.

Generally, Windows 8 creates a restore point for you automatically during Windows Updates and other system maintenance events. If you noticed, there is an option of **Scan for affected programs** that allows to check which programs may be affected by the operation before changes are applied to your system. Did you click on that?

Comment: ye, I did. The restore point was just a few days back.. it's strange that After Effects works ok. During the restoration process I was moving some documents over from the C drive to D, because I got an error that there wasn't enough space on the disk. But I copied all of them back, once I got the system running..

Comment: okey, so I got it working now... still need to figure out that PS and AI though.